# Vigenere Cipher - Inexplicable Nuance

Tags: c, algorithm, encryption, cs50, vigenere

I am implementing a Vigenere cipher in C. My solution kept enciphering the plain-text incorrectly. I thus decided to make a (somewhat arbitrary) change to my code. The aim of the alteration was simply to make the code more readable, by positioning my variables better, and giving them more appropriate names. However, This change has now caused the solution to encipher properly; ***I can't explain why the current solution works over the original one***. Could someone perhaps enlighten me?

**original.c**

```
//...code to validate user input

string k = argv[1]; //'argv' being a main method parameter
string str = GetString();

//Encrypt using vigenere
for (int i = 0, n = strlen(str); i < n; i++) {

    /*An int to keep track of which char to use from the keyword.
    Only increment if str[i] was alphabetic.*/
    int k_index = 0;
    int k_len = strlen(k);
    char letter_key = tolower(k[k_index % k_len]);

    //Checking if str[i] is alphabetic
    if (isalpha(str[i])) {

        //Checking if str[i] is uppercase
        if (isupper(str[i])) {

            //enciphering using vigenere formula
            str[i] = ((str[i] - 'A') + (letter_key - 'a')) % 26 + 'A';
            printf("%c", str[i]);
            k_index++;
        }

        //If not uppercase, it must be lowercase
        else {
            //enciphering using vigenere formula
            str[i] = ((str[i] - 'a') + (letter_key - 'a')) % 26 + 'a';
            printf("%c", str[i]);
            k_index++;
        }

    } else {
        printf("%c", str[i]);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Key: "chasi"
Input/Result: "my plaintext" ---> "oa rnckpvgzv" 
Should be: "of pdikutwfv"
```

---

**updated.c**

```
//...code to validate user input

string k = argv[1];
string str = GetString();

//Encrypt using vigenere
for (int i = 0, j = 0, n = strlen(str); i < n; i++) {

    /*"int j" is to keep track of which char to use from the keyword.
    Only increment if str[i] was alphabetic.*/

    int k_len = strlen(k);
    char letter_key = tolower(k[j % k_len]) - 'a';

    //Checking if str[i] is alphabetic
    if (isalpha(str[i])) {

        //Checking if str[i] is uppercase
        if (isupper(str[i])) {

            //enciphering using vigenere formula
            str[i] = ((str[i] - 'A') + letter_key) % 26 + 'A';
            printf("%c", str[i]);
            j++;
        }

        //If not uppercase, it must be lowercase
        else {
            //enciphering using vigenere formula
            str[i] = ((str[i] - 'a') + letter_key) % 26 + 'a';
            printf("%c", str[i]);
            j++;
        }

    } else {
        printf("%c", str[i]);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Key: "chasi"
Input/Result: "my plaintext" ---> "of pdikutwfv" (correct)
```

Comment: @user3386109 its been corrected

Comment: In the original code, `k_index` is set back to `0` each time through the loop. The updated code sets it to `0` at the beginning, then increments it during the loops.

Comment: @Barmar ahhhh I see! That's why at least the first char is always correct in the original code!

Comment: The variable is NOT the only change. You also changed the "enciphering" lines.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, but the maths behind the enciphering lines is still the same. It's just that the calculation of 'letter_key' is done previously.

Answer (score 3):

The original code does:

```
int k_index = 0;
```

each time through the loop. Then when it does:

```
char letter_key = tolower(k[k_index % k_len]);
```

it's using this `0` value, so `letter_key` is always `tolower(k[0])`. The places where it does `k_index++;` have no effect, because the variable gets zeroed before it gets used again. So you're just using the first character of the key as the whole key.

In the updated code, the variable `j` takes the place of `k_index`. It gets initialized to `0` when the loop starts, not each time through the loop. So when you do:

```
char letter_key = tolower(k[j % k_len]) - 'a';
```

you're using the updated value of `j`. This properly uses the whole key.